Как сделать адресную строку в electron?
В electron приложении есть верхняя панель (alt меню).
Как в эту панель сделать адресную строку (пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), которая будет показывать адрес сайта в интернете и в которой можно менять адрес сайта (то есть копировать, вставлять и т.д.)?
